# Textpad shows non-printable charater(hex 02) in different way going from windows 7 to windows 10

Tags: textpad, non-printing-characters

With the same version of TextPad the look is different. It would be very convinient with the same display of the hex "02" character in windows 10.

I would like to know why this is changed, and even better how to get the same look in windows 10 as in windows 7.

[The character after the string THIS_PERIOD is displayed as special sign, easy to see in the file, but in windows 10 this is a space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDCyc.png)